# How can I change the color of label with * in text

Tags: html, css

I have labels like this

`<label> User Type*: </label>`

Now is there any way to change the color of label to red if text contains * in it only with CSS

All I can do is edit `css`. I can't use  Javascript.

Comment: No. This is not possible with pure CSS. Here is a simple solution with jQuery - http://jsfiddle.net/kR6Cs/

Comment: put the * in another element such as span (`<span>*</span>`), then style the span

Comment: CSS cannot access anything within the DOM, hence, CSS cannot look at the text within the `<label>` element and pick a style accordingly.

Comment: Aren't you allowed also to edit the mark-up for that and then putting a class in order for you to control the text-color of the label?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, without javascript you won't be able to style only the `*`. what you will need to do is to put the `*` in its own element, and style that element.

Example:

HTML

```
<label> User Type<span>*</span>: </label>
```

CSS

```
label span { color: red; }
```

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ee9L3/

EDIT: looks like i misread the question. No there's no way to do what you want. The easiest alternative would be to just add a class to the label.

HTML

```
<label class='required'>User Type*: </label>
```

CSS

```
label.required { color: red; }
```

Comment: But that only changes the colour of the * not the label.

Comment: It seems like the OP wants to change the color of the `label` **if** it contains a `*`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change only the * in CSS. I would recommend doing something like this:

`<label> User Type<span class="red">*</span></label>`

If you can't change the HTML, you may be out of luck. I guess you could do something like this in your CSS:

```
label:after {
   content: "*";
   color: red;
}
```

Comment: It would create an additional * but it would be red. http://jsfiddle.net/N7Bq7/ :after does not have the greatest support with older versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but - If you can't edit the html and can't use javascript - there is no way to do this with just css (yet?!)

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 had a very short-lived :contains() pseudo class if I remember correctly. Unfortunately it has been removed from the spec and there is no way to do this with CSS alone.

IE had a means of attaching JavaScript behaviors to CSS using .HTC files. However, that only works in IE and not in any other browser, so it's not a good answer.

You would need some sort of JavaScript or access to the HTML itself. That's the only way. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy. This is a mixture of previous answers.

HTML:

```
<label class='required'>Direcció <span class="red">*</span></label>
```

CSS:

```
label.required>span.red{ color: red; }
```